# Why is it not possible to implement a functional interface using a lambda expression outside a class?

Tags: java, lambda

One can implement a functional interface this way:

```
abstract class predicate implements Predicate<Integer> {

    public static boolean test(int e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or this way:

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = e -> true;
```

The following code compiles:

```
import java.util.function.*;


abstract class predicate implements Predicate<Integer> {

    public static boolean test(int e) {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(predicate.test(2));
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't and gives a "class, interface, or enum expected" error:

```
import java.util.function.*;

Predicate<Integer> predicate = e -> true;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(predicate.test(2));
    }
}
```

For the above code to work, I'd have to implement the interface inside the main class. Why?

Comment: All code (sans imports) must be within a class declaration.  That is how the language was designed.

Comment: You can't declare a standalone variable of *any* type in Java. All variables are inside a class/interface.

Comment: @WJS but you can declare interfaces outside classes. Or are there no functional differences between interfaces and classes internally?

Comment: An interface is similar to a class in its construct.  It is implicitly abstract and public.  It can also be put in its own file.

Comment: @khelwood I was not declaring a standalone variable, I was implementing a functional interface. There is no functional difference between implementing a functional interface via a lambda or the implements key word.

Comment: @lostperson well, the JLS (and the compiler) beg to differ. Asking "*why?*" is pointless, the answer will always be: because the JLS says so.

Comment: @lostperson.  `Predicate<Integer> predicate = e -> true;`  `predicate` is a variable.  But why are you asking this?  It's no different than asking why methods or fields are case sensitive.  The language either allows it or doesn't.

Comment: @WJS but I feel like I am failing to understand an essential aspect of the language because why is this a variable and the abstract class predicate in the code not a variable?

Comment: @lostperson When / what should control the execution of code outside of a class?

Comment: There are many aspects of the language creation that I don't know the reasons behind.  Sometimes it was just because it wasn't required.  Other reasons were probably that the ultimate benefit was not worth the additional complexity required by the compiler.  In your case it is, imo, easy.  There would be no way to reference the variable or field.  I just accept the constraints and move on.

Comment: "*And does any of you know why the language was designed such that everything must be in a class?*" - Why not ask James Gosling that question? --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: And your not alone in wondering about these.  But I actually have more questions about the exclusion of certain features in the API than the compiler.

Comment: @Turing85 OK, I will remove the comment. But it just seems to be the more general version of this question (for which BTW, I found an interesting answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185109/why-java-does-not-allow-function-definitions-to-be-present-outside-of-the-class.

Comment: `Predicate<Integer> predicate` is a variable of type `Predicate<Integer>`. It holds a single object. It is not functionally equivalent to declaring a type.

Answer (score 0):

Fields (even constant fields) must be defined in the class, and here you're using it like you expect it to be a static constant. Like,

```
public class Main {
    private static final Predicate<Integer> predicate = e -> true; // PREDICATE by convention

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(predicate.test(2));
    }
}
```